# Get current url with parameters passed

Tags: site-url

How can I get the current url in a wordpress page? I have enabled clean urls, but I want the url without the clean urls. For example

```
http://example.com/?page_id=1
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/my-page
```

Comment: what for do you need such url?

Comment: Have you thought changing your permalinks? You can find the permalink settings in your admin area

Answer (score 1):

Add the following custom function in functions.php file of your theme to get the **page url without the clean urls**

```
function get_page_custom_link() {
    global $post;
    $link = '';        
   if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) )
        $link = home_url('/');
    else
        $link = home_url( '?page_id=' . $post->ID );    
    return $link;
}
```

And call it in your template as following

```
<?php echo get_page_custom_link(); ?>
```

**Note : It will not work for other urls( attachments, tags, taxonomy, post etc.)**

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [url_to_postid function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid)

Used as follows (example is from singular theme part eg. single.php, page.php):

```
$url = get_permalink();
$postid = url_to_postid( $url );
$post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
switch ( $post_type ){
    case 'post':
        $not_nice_permalink = home_url( '?p=' . $post->ID );
        break;
    case 'page':
        $not_nice_permalink = home_url( '?page_id=' . $post->ID );
        break;
}
```

Note that this does not return the post id for custom post types.